# az cli schedule-query --condition not working

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am trying to provision Azure Alert using az cli scheduled-query command, but having difficulties with the --condition.

Below is what I am trying to provision via az cli:

[image]

And the command I use is:

```
az monitor scheduled-query create --condition "avg 'AggregatedValue' > 1 at least 1 violations out of 5 aggregated points" \
                                  --condition-query "KubeEvents \n| where ClusterName =~ 'esg-aks-asse-aks-d'\n| where ObjectKind =~ 'Pod'\n| where Reason =~ 'BackOff'\n| project TimeGenerated, Name, ObjectKind, Reason, Message, Namespace, Count\n| summarize AggregatedValue=sum(Count) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m) \n" \
                                  --name "esg-txc-dev-podbackoff" \
                                  --resource-group "<myrg>" \
                                  --scopes "<myscope>" \
                                  --target-resource-type "Kubernetes service" \
                                  --action-groups "<myactiongroup>" \
                                  --description "Pod Back Off Alert" \
                                  --evaluation-frequency "5m" \
                                  --severity 2 \
                                  --skip-query-validation false \
                                  --window-size "5m"
```

However, I receive below error when I run it:

[image]

Is there anyway / guideline how to get equivalent --condition for the one in Azure Portal UI?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to get this working as well.
Finally found it due to the error I got after trying to create an alertrule:
Stating "["METRIC COLUMN" from]"

```
usage error: --condition {avg,min,max,total,count} ["METRIC COLUMN" from]
                         "QUERY_PLACEHOLDER" {=,!=,>,>=,<,<=} THRESHOLD
                         [resource id RESOURCEID]
                         [where DIMENSION {includes,excludes} VALUE [or VALUE ...]
                         [and   DIMENSION {includes,excludes} VALUE [or VALUE ...] ...]]
                         [at least MinTimeToFail violations out of EvaluationPeriod aggregated points]
```

This made me using something like this

```
$condqry="ApiManagementGatewayLogs | summarize cnt=count() by bin(TimeGenerated,1h)"
$cond= "max cnt from 'QRY1' > 30"

az monitor scheduled-query create
--name "fat-test" 
--condition $cond 
--condition-query QRY1="$condqry" 
--scopes <yourscope> 
--resource-group $ALERT_RESOURCE_GROUP 
--window-size 30m
--evaluation-frequency 30m
--description "Test alert" 
--severity 1
```

Where the "**max cnt from**" is the most important part